# How to recover an SSD (Samsung) after deleting all the namespaces?

Tags: ssd, namespaces

I deleted all the namespaces (2 were present) on a samsung drive (SSD). Now the drive is not being recognized by the system. How do I recover the SSD?

Comment: I have never heard of namespaces on storage devices. Do you mean partitions?

Comment: @wurtel: Yes, they are basically partitions

Comment: @wurtel Namespaces are a special feature of NVMe drives.  Each namespace is treated essentially as a separate drive by Linux, and can have its own partition table and everything.

Answer (score 1):

You should still be able to see `nvme0` in `/dev` -- only the -`nX` entries should be gone.  Try `sudo nvme create-ns -s 100000 -b 4096 /dev/nvme0`, then `sudo nvme attach -n 1 /dev/nvme0`, and see if that gets things working again.